# send an email and sms of application to another user

Tags: android

I want to share an app to another person through mail or sms. For example if I am downloading one app from android market and I want to send that app link to other person, how can i send the link to that person through mail or sms?

Comment: you can send an email and sms from your application programmatically, i thought you want to do this ?

Comment: I want code for send that link to others through email and sms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{
                                 "test@test.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your mail Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Put ur Application URL here");
Email.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

You can send the mail this way, u can include ur Apps Market link in the Body of the mail.

Answer (score 0):

You can do [Browser.SendString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#sendString%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%29), It filter all the (Intent.ACTION_SEND) intent-including twitter/facebook if you installed- from your phone and share what you want.